Disrupt Odoo flow
I am developing an electronic invoicing system with a third party invoice certifier. When there is an error in the invoice and it is not certified, the certifier returns a json with information about the error.
I made a new module that places the errors in the corresponding invoice, but here comes my problem.
I want to launch an alert with “UserError” that tells me that the invoice has not been certified, but when I use “raise UserError”, all the transactions of the transaction that triggered the alert are reverted, therefore the errors are not placed in the invoice view.
On the other hand, if I don't use a “raise UserError”, the errors are placed, but the invoice within Odoo continues its flow and is published, which is not right for my business logic.
This are the error view

But the invoice is published now and this is wrong

I would like to stop the Odoo flow and prevent the invoice from posting and errors from being set on the invoice.
    def certificar_documento(self, url, headers, tree):
        certificar_xml = ET.tostring(tree.getroot(), encoding="UTF-8", method="xml")
        respuesta = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=certificar_xml)
        respuesta_json = respuesta.json()

        return certificar_xml, respuesta_json

    def establecer_error(self, json):
        errores = self.env["errores.fel"]
        for error in json["descripcion_errores"]:
            errores.create(
                {
                    "mensaje_error": error.get("mensaje_error"),
                    "fecha_hora_error": datetime.now(),
                    "account_move_factuas_ids": self.id,
                }
            )

    def facturacion_electronica(self):
        url = "https://certificador.feel.com.gt/fel/procesounificado/transaccion/v2/xml"

        headers = {
            "UsuarioFirma": f"{self.company_id.usuario}",
            "LlaveFirma": f"{self.company_id.llave_firma}",
            "UsuarioApi": f"{self.company_id.usuario}",
            "LlaveApi": f"{self.company_id.llave_api}",
            "Content-Type": "application/xml",
        }

        for factura in self:
            if (
                factura.tipo_factura == "none"
                and factura.move_type != "out_refund"
                and factura.move_type != "in_invoice"
                and not factura.debit_origin_id
            ):
                raise UserError("Debe ingresar el tipo de documento que va a emitir")

            elif factura.debit_origin_id:
                tree = NDEB.generar_nota_debito(self, factura)

            elif factura.move_type == "out_refund":
                tree = NCRE.generar_nota_credito(self, factura)

            elif factura.tipo_factura == "fact" or factura.tipo_factura == "fact_cambiaria":
                tree = FACT.generar_factura(self, factura)

            elif factura.factura_especial:
                tree = FESP.generar_especial(self, factura)

            else:
                continue

            certificar_xml, respuesta_json = self.certificar_documento(url, headers, tree)
            if respuesta_json["resultado"] == False:
                # mensajes_error = "\n".join(error["mensaje_error"] for error in respuesta_json["descripcion_errores"])
                # raise ValidationError(f"La factura no se certificó\n{mensajes_error}")
                self.establecer_error(respuesta_json)
                return
            else:
                factura.numero_autorizacion = respuesta_json["uuid"]
                factura.serie = respuesta_json["serie"]
                factura.numero_dte = respuesta_json["numero"]
                factura.xml_generado = certificar_xml
                factura.fecha_emision = datetime.now()
                fecha_hora_certificado = respuesta_json["fecha"].split("T")
                hora_certificado = fecha_hora_certificado[1].split("-")
                fecha_hora_str = f"{fecha_hora_certificado[0]} {hora_certificado[0]}"
                fecha_hora_time = datetime.strptime(fecha_hora_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                fecha_hora_modificada = fecha_hora_time + timedelta(hours=6)
                factura.fecha_certificacion = fecha_hora_modificada
                factura.xml_certificado = respuesta_json["xml_certificado"]
                factura.certificada = True

                var_numero_autorizacion = respuesta_json["uuid"]
                var_serie = respuesta_json["serie"]
                var_numero_dte = respuesta_json["numero"]
                var_fecha = date.today()

                link_factura = (
                    f"https://report.feel.com.gt/ingfacereport/ingfacereport_documento?uuid={var_numero_autorizacion}"
                )

                mensaje = f"""
                    <strong style='display:block;'>Datos FEL de la factura</strong>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Número de autorización: {var_numero_autorizacion}
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Serie: {var_serie}
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Número DTE: {var_numero_dte}
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Fecha: {var_fecha}
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <a href='{link_factura}' target='_blank'>Ver factura<a/>
                """

                factura.message_post(
                    body=mensaje,
                    body_is_html=True,
                    author_id=self.env.ref("base.partner_root").id,
                    subject="Factura certificada correctamente",
                    message_type="comment",
                    subtype_xmlid="mail.mt_comment",
                )


Introduce two booleans to track invoices that are certified and that have errors. For the ones with errors, do not call super() on them when you override the action post method of the invoice model. Additionally, show a banner for these invoices so that you don't have to raise UserError.
Please make sure to set the flags correctly in your method facturacion_electronica().
class AccountMove(models.Model):
   _inherit = 'account.move'

   certified = fields.Boolean()
   certification_error = fields.Boolean()

   def action_post(self):
      # call your method on uncertified invoices only
      uncertified_invoices = self.filtered(lambda inv: not inv.certified)

      # make sure to set certified=True for successful calls and certification_error=True for erroneous ones inside your method
      uncertified_invoices.facturacion_electronica()

      # filter all successfully certified invoices, no need to check for the error flag because even if it is set to True it must be from previous calls
      certified_invoices = self.filtered(lambda inv: inv.certified)

      # call super method on them while nothing happens for the uncertified invoices
      return super(InvoiceModelName, certified_invoices).action_post()

Add the banner in the form view of account.move:
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" invisible="certified or not ceritifcation_error">
   There was an error certifying this invoice. Please check the error logs.
</div>


That's like how Odoo solved a similar topic: EDI for invoices. Good answer.
